# Django Display more fields in manytomany relationship on admin page

Tags: django, many-to-many, m2m

I have a page build model that has a manytomanyfield
All i want is to display the other columns of the manytomany field model

I have an image model with name and category fields and I want both to display on the admin page in an inline table with a filter instead of a many to many field.

Comment: Could you supply some sample code for your models? What do you mean by *filter instead many-to-many-field*?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `inlines` property of the `ModelAdmin` class.

First, define an `InlineModelAdmin` (the Django documentation covers it [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin)). Then, set the `inlines` property of your page build model to a list or tuple with the class you created. You'll get exactly the behavior you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I totally chucked the inlines idea and went a whole new route. In the end I just built a table with the fields and used some jquery to do a filter. it does exactly what i want.